# Installing library to raspberry pi problems

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I'm trying to install a library to my RPi 3 B, but for some reason when I try to import it in my script, it won't recognize the library.  This is the library:

https://github.com/widgetlords/libwidgetlords

And here are the install instructions:

https://widgetlords.com/pages/getting-started-with-pi-spi-libraries

When I perform the instruction:

```
from widgetlords.pi_spi import *
```

I get the error "No module found called widgetlords.pi_spi".  I have tried installing manually, and also tried using the pip install instruction, but for some reason can not install this module properly.  Any advice??

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the install command (the `dpkg -i` line). And is the module meant for Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: It is meant for Python 3.  I realized this too so set python 3.5.5 to the default.  I am still having trouble.  Were you able to install the lib?

Comment: I'm not even trying. What about the output of the install command I asked about? Add it to your question.

Comment: dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libwidgetlords_1.0.2_armhf.deb': No such file or directory

Comment: `Add it to your question`

Answer (score 1):

Disregard.  Was using Geany as the text editor which defaults to python 2.  Changed it to python 3 which solved the issue